# Floating text side by side using overflow auto

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to get a paragraph to display to the right of another paragraph, however it is currently appearing below it.  I am trying to use overflow auto but am unsure of where it is supposed to go.

[image: Example]

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; float: left;">
    <p style="width: 400px; border-right: 2px solid black;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui purus nascetur ultrices commodo at morbi, eget nulla.
        Ipsum donec amet, facilisis pellentesque lacinia vel quis lacus leo, mollis sit
        lacinia eros dui in, nullam fermentum sollicitudin viverra. Proin cum. Vel ipsum
    </p>
    <p style="padding-left: 5px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et felis, viverra at ullamcorper interdum, suspendisse
        ipsum dolor sint, lacinia nec vestibulum dolor per rutrum, lacus consequat. Architecto
        ultricies ut pellentesque sapien eget sed. Mauris justo nonummy euismod consectetuer
        pellentesque. Etiam metus vestibulum lacinia eget vitae amet, volutpat sem integer
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overflow: auto belongs on the parent div, and you need a width on both floated elements.  Try this:

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; overflow: auto;">
    <p style="float: left; width: 400px; border-right: 2px solid black;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui purus nascetur ultrices commodo at morbi, eget nulla.
        Ipsum donec amet, facilisis pellentesque lacinia vel quis lacus leo, mollis sit
        lacinia eros dui in, nullam fermentum sollicitudin viverra. Proin cum. Vel ipsum
    </p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 400px; padding-left: 5px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et felis, viverra at ullamcorper interdum, suspendisse
        ipsum dolor sint, lacinia nec vestibulum dolor per rutrum, lacus consequat. Architecto
        ultricies ut pellentesque sapien eget sed. Mauris justo nonummy euismod consectetuer
        pellentesque. Etiam metus vestibulum lacinia eget vitae amet, volutpat sem integer
    </p>
</div>​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RymfP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rn8k3/

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; float: left;">
    <p style="width: 48%; border-right: 2px solid black;float:left;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui purus nascetur ultrices commodo at morbi, eget nulla.
        Ipsum donec amet, facilisis pellentesque lacinia vel quis lacus leo, mollis sit
        lacinia eros dui in, nullam fermentum sollicitudin viverra. Proin cum. Vel ipsum
    </p>
    <p style="width:48%;padding-left: 5px;float:left;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et felis, viverra at ullamcorper interdum, suspendisse
        ipsum dolor sint, lacinia nec vestibulum dolor per rutrum, lacus consequat. Architecto
        ultricies ut pellentesque sapien eget sed. Mauris justo nonummy euismod consectetuer
        pellentesque. Etiam metus vestibulum lacinia eget vitae amet, volutpat sem integer
    </p>
</div>​
```

Comment: without an overflow: auto or a clear, this example may look right as-is, but as you start to add more tags below or inside, you will run into problems from the uncleared "float: left" inner paragraphs.

Also, the float:left on the outer DIV will not affect the inner paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a width on the second paragraph and I also think they also need to float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both a `width` and `float:left` for both paragraphs. You do not need `float:left` on the wrapping DIV.

```
<p style="width: 400px; border-right: 2px solid black; float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that does NOT need a width on the second `p` tag:

```
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;position:relative; ">
    <p style="width: 400px; border-right: 2px solid black;display: inline-block;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dui purus nascetur ultrices commodo at morbi, eget nulla.
        Ipsum donec amet, facilisis pellentesque lacinia vel quis lacus leo, mollis sit
        lacinia eros dui in, nullam fermentum sollicitudin viverra. Proin cum. Vel ipsum
    </p>
    <p style="padding-left: 5px;display: inline-block;position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;margin-left:410px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et felis, viverra at ullamcorper interdum, suspendisse
        ipsum dolor sint, lacinia nec vestibulum dolor per rutrum, lacus consequat. Architecto
        ultricies ut pellentesque sapien eget sed. Mauris justo nonummy euismod consectetuer
        pellentesque. Etiam metus vestibulum lacinia eget vitae amet, volutpat sem integer
    </p>
</div>
```